# How to use a different value instead of id

Tags: angular

At this moment, after getting item from .json file:

**catalog-items.service.ts**

```
  /** GET item by id. Will 404 if id not found */
  getCatalogItem(id: number): Observable<CatalogItem> {
    const url = `${this.catalogitemsUrl}/${id}`;
    return this.http.get<CatalogItem>(url);
  }
```

**catalog-item.component.ts**

```
  getCatalogItem(): void {
    const id = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    this.catalogItemsService.getCatalogItem(id)
      .subscribe(catalogitem => this.catalogitem = catalogitem);
  }
```

my dynamic links looks like this: "sitename.com/catalog/**id**"

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'catalog', component: CatalogComponent },
  { path: 'catalog/:id', component: CatalogItemComponent },
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];
```

Is it possible to use another received value instead of id which will be shown if we point our browser directly to sitename.com/catalog/**page_title**? I did not find any implementation examples over the Internet.

Answer (score 1):

I've come across something similar before. Why don't you change your routes so it uses name instead of id:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'catalog', component: CatalogComponent },
  { path: 'catalog/:name', component: CatalogItemComponent },
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];
```

Then your catalog-item-service could take the name as a parameter to retrieve the CatalogItem:

```
getCatalogItem(name: string): Observable<CatalogItem> {
    const url = `${this.catalogitemsUrl}/${name}`;
    return this.http.get<CatalogItem>(url);
  }
```

And change you catalog-component-item to take the name instead:

```
getCatalogItem(): void {
    const name = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('name');
    this.catalogItemsService.getCatalogItem(name)
      .subscribe(catalogitem => this.catalogitem = catalogitem);
  }
```

This does mean you'll need to change you api. But with this implementation, you cannot have duplicate CatalogItem name's either.

Comment: Received error: Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'

Comment: Where did you receive the error? Make sure to change all the typings from number to string.

Comment: Console: ERROR in src/app/catalog-item/catalog-item.component.ts(39,45): error TS2345: Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.

Comment: updated my answer - take a look at catalog-component-item code in my answer

Comment: Compiled succesfully but now page is empty and it doesn't showing me results from {{catalogitem.title}} (for example). Error in browser console: {body: {…}, url: "api/catalogitems/null", headers: HttpHeaders, status: 404, statusText: "Not Found"}
body:
error: "'catalogitems' with id='null' not found". It's still looking for id?

Comment: Fixed routing to 'name' instead 'id' but still empty

Comment: Error in browser: body: {error: "'catalogitems' with id='ruby' not found"}
headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: ƒ}
status: 404
statusText: "Not Found"
url: "api/catalogitems/ruby"

Comment: Looks like a problem with your api...it's expecting a number instead of a string by the looks of it.

Comment: I'll fix my api then. Thanks for your help